# hide/show a button on drop down list select?

Tags: asp.net, button, html-select

I am looking for a way to hide or show a button only when an option is selected from a drop down list. Can this be done? I wasn't able to find anything... probably because I'm not searching properly. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

What i get is that you want to hide/display your button on certain values selected from drop down list.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="selectionchange();">
    <option value="abc" >abc</option>
    <option value="xyz" >xyz</option>
</select>
<input id="btn"  type="submit" class="button" value="Confirm" />

function selectionchange()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(str == 'abc')
{
       document.getElementById('btn').style.display='none';
}
else if(str == 'xyz')
{
   document.getElementById('btn').style.display='block';
}
}
```

for display/hiding you can also use this

```
document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility='visible';
```